# Cross-sections in subsets of $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $u (\mathbf{x}) \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ be a binary label assigned to points
$\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N$, and let $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ be a
fixed vector.

Specifically we will assume that $u(\mathbf{x}) = u (\mathbf{x}/ \| \mathbf{x} \|)$ depends only on the direction of $\mathbf{x}$.

Prove or disprove:

For any such $u$, there exists a vector $\mathbf{w}$ such that the set of points $\{ u (\mathbf{x}) = 1 \wedge \mathbf{w}^{\top} \mathbf{x}= t \wedge ||\mathbf{x}|| = 1\}$ has the same volume for all $t\in\mathbb R$.

I think this statement is false, but I am having trouble coming up with a good counter-example $u$.

Comment: What do you mean by volume? Your sets are of measure zero since they're contained in planes.

Comment: @Theorem Surface area?

Comment: I see, and how did you define $N-1$ area of an arbitrary set which doesn't have to be a manifold? Since $u$ is not too constrained I guess you could get whacky sets.

Comment: @Theorem Let's assume that the sets are smooth enough. I just want a counterexample $u$, so we can assume what we want about $u$.

Comment: The thing is that assuming things are smooth enough it becomes true in my opinion, since if $u^{-1}(1)$ contains some "small cone coming out from the origin", then we can construct $w$ s.t the intersection is infinite area for all planes perpendicular to $w$.

Comment: Assume the sets are bounded. I'll add this to the question @Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple example I can think of is in $\mathbb R^3$ with $u=1$ at all points. For any $w$, the sets in question are the intersection of $\mathbb S^2$ with planes perpendicular to $w$, which are 1-dim curves (and their volume is their "length")
$$\Gamma_t=\mathbb S^2\cap \left \{ w^\top x=t \right \}$$
So is it true that $\text{length}(\Gamma_t)$ is independant of $t$? It is a clear no, since for a large enough $t$ we have a plane far enough from the sphere so that $\Gamma_t=\emptyset$ and $\text{length}(\Gamma_t)=0$, while for $t=0$ we have $\Gamma_0$ a great circle with $\text{length}(\Gamma_0)=2\pi$.

[image]